# "Drupal-X" tags versus "version-x" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we use, for example, [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) or [version-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6)?

Comment: For a bit more background on why this happened, you might want to [read my answer](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23/is-it-necessary-to-use-both-the-tags-drupal-6-and-drupal-7/99#99) on why we, in the WordPress SE community, have problems with an overload of `[wordpress-N]` tags, and changing to `[version-N]` might be a solution there. But of course, the Drupal versioning policy is different, and this requires community discussion. I only gave an outsiders view.

Comment: I am closing this question as it is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using version-x tag styles don't add any value compared to use drupal-x. In my opinion, using the version-x tag is too generic, and is harder to understand, especially for outsiders.

If a random new user, see a question tagged version-x, he would need to think about what that version number means. Some modules like views have major releases, so what version are we talking about. Drupal also has minor releases, so if a user wanted to ask a question about Drupal 7.6, he could tag it both [version-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7) and [version-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6).

On the other hand, if you use the drupal style tags, it's quite clear what we are talking about. Anybody seeing a drupal-x tag, will know that this question is about or related to drupal 6. It's simpler and easier to understand.

Tags is a great source of filtering questions. Either by marking them as interesting or ignore. This value will be lost, if tags are made too generic, as they will stop being useful to filter questions.

Comment: +1 The Drupal community doesn't even refer to it as "version 7" or "version 6". The only popular non-"Drupal 7" variant is "d7", so if it had to be changed (it shouldn't), that'd be the better alternative.

Comment: A short tag like "D7" is not much useful, and it's not clear to all users what it means. Considering that drupal.SE is also for users who don't know Drupal as perfectly as other users do, I would avoid using too short tags like "D7."

Comment: Tags are kind of organic in nature, so whatever people gravitate toward is what sticks. But I like drupal-6, drupal-7, and so on because I know what that means immediately. I wouldn't bother with tagging point releases unless there is some kind of event that makes a point release notable. In which case, people will start using drupal-7.3 (or whatever) naturally.

Answer (score 2):

We should use [version-x] tags. The reason behind this is that:

- drupal.SE is about Drupal. Differently from stackoverflow.com, questions that are not pertinent to Drupal are off-topic.
- The version reported in the tag is not only the Drupal version, but also the version of every module. There is just a module that doesn't follow the usual version schema, but that module is compatible with any version of Drupal; Drush 4 is not the version for Drupal 4, but Nodewords 6.x is the version for Drupal 6.
- We don't need compatibility with stackoverflow.com, as [drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) is a tag that is used on SO, but not on drupal.SE. The compatibility is kept, anyway, as the [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) is kept as synonym of [version-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6). Users who try to use [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) would still see it, and questions using [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) migrated from SO would be changed to use [version-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6).
- Tags like [version-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-6) are less prone to be used when they are not needed. Users would probably choose [drupal-6](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-6) on the basis that the question is about Drupal; this is not the case of tags like [drupal-views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-views), which should suggest the tag is for questions about Views.

Comment: To me, the second point raised here is the best reason *not* to use 'version-x' tags. Using a tag means that all questions tagged with it, are related. However Views 3 and Admin Menu 3 are not related in any way so it doesn't make sense to make them share the 'version-3' tag.

Comment: Agreed. A version-x tag would only get a meaning by using a combination of two tags, for example "views version-3" or "drush version-4". That's imho unecessary complex. Also, I haven't seen the tags drupal-6 or drupal-7 used incorrectly but maybe that is because kiamlaluno already retagged all of them ;)