# Revert the tag drupal-x -> version-x tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

In [“Drupal-X” tags versus “version-x” tags](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/drupal-x-tags-versus-version-x-tags), the question was brought up whether core version tags should take the form of [drupal-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-7) or [version-7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-7). Despite the top-voted answer being that it should be the former for obvious reasons, a moderator has decided to unilaterally make all drupal-x tags synonyms of version-x.

In [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), the role of the moderator is outlined:

> Even with active community self-regulation, moderators occasionally need to intervene. **Moderators are human exception handlers**, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

In this case, it's the moderators who have, with their unilateral decision to reorganize the core tags, potentially brought to the entire community to a screaming halt.  It makes it much harder to find useful information.

For all [the reasons googletorp mentioned](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/drupal-x-tags-versus-version-x-tags/103#103) in the aforementioned meta discussion topic, please remove the tag synonym and use the tags the community has decided to use. It's not the role of moderators to constantly reorganize the organic, correct use of tags.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because neither the drupal-7 nor the version-7 tags are used on the main site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question on meta was brought on after the tags was changes. I had a talk with @kiamlaluno on the drupal chat after that. I didn't agree with his decision, but that wasn't really my point. Something so general as the names of the most used tags, should be a community decision, which was how the question arose on meta.

I have reverted the tags back to original. Should the vote fall in favor to the version-x style tags, it's no big deal to change it back again.